# wordpress gives me code review of html escape(you have to escape variable when they are echoed) please give me solution?

Tags: php, wordpress

below is the url of image for coding lines.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUHjB.jpg

Comment: i think you have missed esc-html somewhere in other line of code in you plugin. please check all sentence when you are printing value/output

Comment: Check this documentation for wordpress standard, Might be you missed it somewhere in your code. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/#escaping-securing-output

Answer (score 0):

Before start html code in php file you should add php ending code " **?>**"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NE9t1.png